# SpingBoot mq web app stops consuming messages

Tags: spring, spring-boot, mq

I noticed strange problem in my web app.
Web app is hosted on AWS, is made in SpringBoot framework and its main responsibility is consuming messages from MQ. Messages are consumed one by one - there is no concurrency.

I am using MQQueueConnectionFactory class to prepare my connection,
I properly set parameters like:

- host
- port
- queue manager
- channel
- int property
- client reconnect options

and all ssl required parameters. 
All seems to work well all the time until something happen and messages from MQ are not consumed. I can see messages which are waiting for being consumed, but web app does not consume it. After web app is restarted all work fine. I think it can be problem with connection which seems to be broken after some time (several days). I set reconnect option to connection factory class and for now I do not know what to do else to fix it.

Have you ever met similar problem? Do you have any clues?

Comment: any logs when the event happens?

Comment: Acutally sometimes I can see timeout error, but after that connection seems to work normally... so far do not know what can cause the issue - could it be AWS?